# How to change an object shape in typescript based on a specific property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am building a questionnaire renderer, and there are many types of questions (for the sake of this question I will only use 2 types).

I want to make sure I am using the best Typescript pattern for changing my object shape.

The types of questions are:

**text**:

```js
type TextQuestion = {
  label: string;
  type: 'text';
  answer?: string;
}
```

**multiple-options**:

```js
type MultipleOptionsQuestion = {
  label: string;
  type: 'multiple-options';
  answer: Array<string>;
}
```

Now, what I want is to use these 2 types of questions in my renderer in a way where each renderer has a different shape:

e.g.

```js
function renderer(question){
  return {
    'text': renderTextQuestion(question),
    'multiple-options': renderMultipleOptionsQuestion(question)
  }[question.type]
}


function renderTextQuestion(question){
  question.answer // This is a string
}

function renderMultipleOptionsQuestion(question){
  question.answer // This is an array of strings
}
```

Is there a way of doing this by exporting only one type `Question` or should I export one type for each question type and then extend them from a "BaseQuestion" type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context of what you want to achieve by having the option to **export** only one type of **Question**, the answer is Yes, and you can declare a third question **type** with **type and answer** using **unions**, and then,pass this **Question** as **args** to the **renderer fxn**

An example code stub could be in this format:

```
type TextQuestion = {
   label: string;
   type: 'text';
   answer?: string; 
}

type MultipleOptionsQuestion = {
   label: string;
   type: 'multiple-options';
   answer: Array<string>;
}

type Question = {
   label: string,
   type: 'text' | 'multiple-options',
   answer? : string | Array<string>
}

function renderer(question: Question){
  if(question.type === 'text'){
     // perform logic here
  }else if(question.type === 'multiple-options'){
    //perfrom logic here
  }else{
   //other code stub logic here
 }
}
```